# Extract text in excel

Tags: excel

I tried a lot of solutions (found in this website) but unfortunatelly those didn't work.
The example:
A1 cell contents:

`<img src="/images/here/green_apple.jpg" alt="Green Apple - from Midland (123)">`

I have to extract texts into 2 cells:
B1 cell displays the path: /images/here/green_apple.jpg
B2 cell displays the description: Green Apple - from Midland (123)

thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In B1:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""",REPT(" ",99)),99,99))
```

IN C1:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""",REPT(" ",99)),297,99))
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for the Quick help. After some changes (maybe the Excel different in other language - needed to cange the functions name and "," to ";"). It works perfectly. :)

Comment: @Sotech yes in the US and some other the delimiter is `,` while in many European and Asian countries it is `;` glad you could figure out the issue.

Comment: You could do it with `find` but _now_ I see why you did not ^_^ I am never going to grow up to be like you ;_;